# How to make selenium webdriver click button every X min with captcha?

Tags: selenium, automation, webdriver, click, listener

There is a website with captcha that should be clicked "i m not a robot" every 20 min.

Does selenium even have ability to time-click button?

[image: ddd]

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do a time click in selenium. Just do a loop with a sleep or something.

I'm not going to provide code for that because it doesn't really solve your problem.

You might want to do some research into [how those "I'm not a robot" captchas work.](https://www.wired.com/2014/12/google-one-click-recaptcha/) Because using a robot to time click it probably isn't going to cut it.